# Unable to limit the height of a table inside a Bootstrap Panel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've got an MVC 5 / Bootstrap app that has a table embedded in a panel, as follows:

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="panel-heading">Life List Counts</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col1</th>
                    <th>Col2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Col1Data
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Col2Data
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to limit the maximum height of the table to something like 200px and then have the rest of the contents scroll vertically inside the panel. I've been unsuccessful in all my attempts. I've tried putting style heights on the panel and table and neither seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the .panel-body height and overflow to auto

```
.panel-body {
   height: 200px;
   overflow: auto;
  }
```

If you want to keep the table header fixed there is and article here: [fixed header table](http://geekswithblogs.net/freestylecoding/archive/2011/04/19/html-table-with-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body.aspx)
that looks quite interesting.

Comment: Nice. I thought I tried that. But I guess not because when I created that styling, it worked. Thank you.